# Array of objects and Table View

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have an Array of objects like this:

```
var Dogs : [Dog] = [Dog]()
```

To give you an example it looks like this when you print it :

```
[Dog {
    name = Dog1;
    age = 9;

}, Dog {
    name = Dog2;
    age = 4;

}]
```

I want to show this element in a Table View so I use this classical function :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


        cell.titleLabel.text = Dogs[indexPath.row]["name"]! as? String

        return cell
    }
```

But I get an ERROR :

```
fatal error: Array index out of range
```

Comment: Take a look at your tableView's `numberOfRowsInSection` and make sure that it is returning the number of items in your data source array, and not more.

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection returns 2 like the number of objects in the Array

Comment: What is the value of `indexPath.row` when the program crashes?

Comment: JAL : it is 0 when it crashes

Comment: Show the actual code where the data is initialized. numberOfRowsInSection should be returning Dogs.count.

Comment: Are you sure the array has been initialized?  What is `Dogs.count` when you get the crash?

Comment: When I use return dogs.count in the function numberOfRowsinsection there is no crash but the tableView is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let dog = Dogs[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = dog.name

    return cell
}
```